# How to implement message before redirect in angularjs using ngdialog?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

How to create unsave change in angularjs using ngdialog.

Eg: currently we are in page1 some fields we are edited. directly we going to page2 or somewhere that time ngdialog need to popup and ask if your move data will be lost. do you want to continue? with options:  save&move, cancel and discard&move. 
if i choose cancel stay same page. if i choose discard&move discard the details what we enter. if i choose save&move save the details and move to corresponding page anyone help me this..

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `onbeforeunload`-function from plain JS:

```
$scope.view = {};

$scope.view.dirty = true;

$scope.$watch('view.dirty', function (oldV, newV) {
    if (newV) {
        window.onbeforeunload = function(){
            return "Did you save your stuff?";
        };
    } else {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: can u give me runable sample? @Johannes Jander

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a site where other people do your work. Try to implement the code I gave you and if you still have problems ask back.

Comment: at least tell me the process how to do?@Johannes Jander

Comment: Set `$scope.view.dirty` to false in the first lines of your controller. Then set an `ng-change` handler on your input fields in the HTML, bound to a function in your controller's `$scope`. In the function of that handler, set `$scope.view.dirty` to true.